# Q-Puzzle on $\mathbb F_7$

Tags: mathematics, visual, no-computers

My high school math student had to solve this puzzle for his homework. I made it harder by not telling you what is the definition of $\mathbb{F}_7$. Neither why letter **Q** is used and which of his chapter this is.

**Your aim is to reconstitute the original image and discover the pattern. Would you use your technique for any random picture and $\mathbb F_{17}$**?

[image]

Note: the LaTeX mathbb font and color (blue) are different from the ones in puzzling.se, but that's not part of the puzzle (it was a URL link in the image).

Note bis: while it could be easier to solve it thanks to computers, I will **favor** no computers solutions and math computations. That's why `no-computers` tag for this puzzle.

Comment: While many image stitching algorithms require partial overlap, I suspect numerical methods could get you most if not all the way to the reconstruction.

Comment: @Galen You made me add the `no-computers` tag :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I get the picture

> A **toucan**
>
>  [image]
>
>  I think the maths connection relates to the [Farey sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farey_sequence) of order $7$.
>
>  Some sequence can be see in the skip-1 vertical sequence in the original arrangement which translates to horizontal placings in the solved picture.
>
>  Thanks to @MacGyver88 for pointing the way.

Comment: Well! That's a correct `no-computers` answer. However, would you use your technique if it was $\mathbb F_{17}$? You still get my +1 ;)

Comment: I decided to change the puzzle's aim tanks to your answer ;)

Comment: Of course, F7 is rot13(Tnybvf svyrq bs beqre 7 (v.r. svryq bs vagrtref zbqhyb 7)). So, the table may be rot13(n xvaq bs nqqvgvba/zhygvcyvpngvba gnoyr bire S7).

Comment: Ah thanks. I was trying to be stealthy. :)

Comment: @JKHA is it good to change a puzzle once an answer has been posted?

Comment: @WeatherVane, I think we should see it as you made me improve my puzzle thanks to your answer! And you definitely deserve +1

Comment: @JKHA rot13(Vs V unq gubhtug nobhg vg orsberunaq, V jbhyq unir ahzorerq gur gvyrf ba gurve onpx orsber phggvat gurz, fb V unq gur bevtvany frdhrapr naq gur evtug bevragngvba. Gura fbyirq vg ahzrevpnyyl ba n genafcnerag furrg, svanyyl pbirevat naq vairegvat vg. Ohg ol gur gvzr V unq gurz phg, vg jnf gbb yngr).

Comment: Alright, I understand the issue. I've decided to select your answer as first answer to original puzzle :)

Answer (score 2):

> The subimages are permuted using an affine map in $\mathbb F_7^2$. I wrote a quick program that lets me adjust the affine map using keypresses until the image is correct, and this is the result:
> [image]
> You can read off the exact affine map by hand if you are so inclined, by comparing the positions of tiles that are supposed to be adjacent, but I figured this was more fun and also provided a more visual solution.

Comment: Congrats! That is the answer I wanted to be found ;) if I could give two selected answers, I would for yours

Comment: You can change your selection if you really want to do that.

Comment: That would no be fair according to the comments on @WeatherVane's answer, that's partially my fault, I admit